# Get system locale in Windows 8 Metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, .net-4.5

in Windows 8 C# WindowsStore app if I call

```
System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion
```

I get US, although in Control Panel - Region I have location and language = UK...

**How do I get country of the device NOT using geolocation?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var region = new Windows.Globalization.GeographicRegion();
```

[Parameterless constructor of GeographicRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206796.aspx) sreates a GeographicRegion object that defaults to the user's home region.